# Proving the equality of two infinite products

Tags: infinite-product

This question is essentially the same as [this earlier question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662119/proving-an-identity-among-jacobi-theta-and-dedekind-functions). However, since Jacobi theta functions might be misleading in the title, in the following I just ask the exact question without prior history to it.

How to prove the following equality?

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^{2n-1})=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1-q^n}{1-q^{2n}}\right)$$

$q=e^{2\pi i \kappa}$ for some $\kappa\in\mathbb{C}$ can be assumed.

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has the form you described. Anyway, multiply both sides by $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 - q^{2n})$.

Comment: Yes, I give $q$ in this form since that is how it is usually formally written when dealing with Jacobi theta functions. Thank you for the hint, it sounds like a logical direction to look into. I will try and see where it leads.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a hint by [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan) the solution becomes completely trivial. Multiplying both sides by $\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{2n}\right)$ we have

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^{2n-1})\left(1-q^{2n}\right)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-q^{n}\right)$$

On the left hand side the first bracket probes terms with $(1-q^{\text{odd}})$ while the second bracket probes $(1-q^{\text{even}})$. Multiplying both together straightforwardly gives the right hand side.